# Is there a way to measure symmetry in general?

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

I sometimes see structures that are 'almost symmetric' - like in, 'if only one changed this one thing/few things, then it would be symmetric'; this had lead me to think about whether there is any meaningful way in which one could quantify symmetry in general - and which form it might take? Something akin to a 'stress tensor', perhaps?

What I'm imagining is something that would allow us to say 'A is more/less symmetric than B', possibly adding 'along ....'.

Comment: Well, symmetry is usually measured by the number of lines of symmetry. The more of them you have, the more symmetric the shape.

Comment: @TavishMusic That sounds really interesting - could you elaborate bit in an answer perhaps? Like what it is, and where I can learn more about the subject.

Comment: @TavishMusic Sorry, I commented before I searched. I find several references to lines of symmetry in plane geometry - does this concept generalise well?

Comment: Oh yes, this is how symmetry is defined in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, so suppose we have a shape. Draw a line that cuts the shape into two parts. If the two parts are reflections of each other across the line (think of it as a mirror), then that line is said to be one of symmetry.

For instance, a circle has $ \infty$ lines of symmetry (any line passing through its center). A square has $4$, two of its diagonals and two lines (vertical and horizontal) passing through the centre and parallel to two sides. But any randomly-drawn messy shape probably does not have any line of symmetry.

Comment: I will accept your answer - the next question, in these times of category theory, will inevitably be how to express this is terms of functors and natural transformations. That's one for better minds than me, though :-)

Comment: I wish I could do that, but I haven’t been taught these yet, sorry :)